# javascript regex returning null, trying to get text between parentheses

Tags: javascript, regex, match

Trying to get "Table 2" or whatever table number it might be (sometimes 2 digits) into a variable. Any idea why this is returning `null`?

```
 var productText = '25-08-12 Boat Cruise (Table 2)';
 var rgx = /^\(\)$/;
 var newText = productText.match(rgx);
 alert(newText);
```

Comment: no offense, but the real answer to "Why?" is "You have no idea what you are doing." Someone will probably post a properly formed regex for this particular problem but you might want to take a step back and do some reading/comprehension on regular expressions *in general* before trying to apply it to even a trivial problem. See [Cargo-Cult Programming](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CargocultProgramming.aspx)

Comment: Of course posting an answer with an answer which isn't a solution but instead posting a link to a 'famous' programmer isn't being fanboy or cargo-cult.

Comment: You're right, I don't have much idea how to use regex. I tried to do some reading and figure it out, and this is the results I got. Sorry 32bitkid, but sometimes in the interest of time it's better to ask of the helpful community than spend 2 extra hours on something.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the following instead:

```
var rgx = /\(([^)]+)\)/;
var match = productText.match(rgx);
var newText = match && match[1];
// newText's value will be "Table 2" if there is match; null otherwise
```

When you have `/^\(\)$/`, you are actually trying to [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) the string `"()"`, no more, no less. Instead, you should match, anywhere in the text, a `(`, store everything between it and the next `)` in a capturing group `([^)]+)`, so that you can refer to the captured group later on with `match[1]`.

If you want just the number, use `/\(Table (\d+)\)/`.

Comment: Should be `var newText = match && match[1];` since `match` may evaluate to `null`, and trying to access `match[1]` would throw in that case.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: Right, thanks, I've edited my answer to account for that.

Comment: I don't recommend putting the `var` statement *inside* the `if` statement, since that implies that the variable is declared only conditionally, i.e. only if the if-condition is met. This is of course not true, and the variable is declared unconditionally. Therefore, it would be more appropriate to declare the variable at the top of the code, and then put a simple assignment inside the `if` statement.

Comment: I *generally* agree with that, but it really depends on what OP wants to do if there is a match or not.

Comment: Well, I mean generally. Variable declarations should not be put inside compound statements. That can lead to confusion, and misunderstanding.

Comment: more specifically in my application, productText is loading the name of a product that will always have (Table #) in it. Then, I change a select-box to automatically reflect the table # in the shopping cart. It's basically a hack so that when the back button is pressed I can restore all the previous jquery changes based on the cart selection - if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
var rgx = /\((.*)\)/
```

Will capture the table number into a group.

Your regex currently says

'give me () at the beginning (^) and the end of the string ($)'.

Comment: So, I see a guy with a bruised eye holding his hands in the air `:P`

Answer (score 0):

The ^ means a line start and

the $ means a line end.

Also, you need something to match the text inside the `()`, for example: `.*`

Having that pointed, `/^\(\)$/` would only match to `()`.

Then, a working example could be:

```
var productText = '25-08-12 Boat Cruise (Table 2)';
var rgx = /\(.*\)/;
var newText = productText.match(rgx)[0];
newText = newText.replace('(','');
newText = newText.replace(')','');
alert(newText);
```

---

After [seeing what you needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12548570/javascript-regex-returning-null-trying-to-get-text-between-parentheses/12548734#comment16899654_12548581), I would recommend the use of [jQuery's data](http://api.jquery.com/data/).